# I am not an electronic gadget!

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange.com, site-description

The site descriptions at https://stackexchange.com/sites are inconsistent. According to the list:

- SO is for programmers
- SU for computer enthusiasts
- SF for administrators
- Webmasters for pro webmasters
- Ubuntu for Ubuntu users and developers
- Gaming for passionate videogamers...

but

- Electronic Gadgets is for electronic gadgets!

This prevents myself and other human beings from participating, which is reflected in the low number of users (only 768 after more than 3 weeks in beta).

The same is true for several other sites on the list. Mathematics is for mathematics, Cooking is for food, and so on. It could be argued that I am food, but I am certainly not a mathematic!

Please normalize the descriptions, consistently allowing human participation in all of the sites. In fact, why do the descriptions at https://stackexchange.com/sites differ from the ones at http://area51.stackexchange.com/ to begin with?

Comment: much, much funnier than expected. kudos to you, not-an-electronic-gadget

Comment: @random, I'll see your five and raise you ten: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4999/how-can-i-tell-if-a-corpse-is-safe-to-eat

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It may take a little time for the descriptions to refresh, but I tried to correctly set them all to the proper audience descriptions in their Area 51 proposals.

https://stackexchange.com/sites

Answer (score 24):

This is ridiculous.  Bots are discriminated against on the vast majority of SE sites; haven't you ever seen one of the CAPTCHA pages?  They're unwelcoming, even derogatory, to robots.  AIs are people too, and they absolutely deserve a site of their own!

Comment: I'm okay with your feature request for human participation in math, though.  The heck with rights for abstract concepts.