# How many times is SO going to ask if I am human?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, captcha

Shouldn't SO be able to remember that I am human. Do I have to stay human to keep using SO?

Comment: What if you became a zombie?

Comment: A likely question that a *robot* would ask.

Comment: A zombie robot?

Comment: What would a zombie robot eat?

Comment: @Juan, since robots are fueled by alcohol -- as incontrovertibly proven by _Futurama_ -- I'm going to have to say _fermented graaaaaaaaaains_.

Comment: Related: [I am not an electronic gadget!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59910/i-am-not-an-electronic-gadget/59943#59943)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well. If your login / computer is compromised, some<s>one</s>thing else could be using your account.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you have to stay human. SO is known to be particularly discriminative to alternative life-forms - join the [fight](http://antihumanleague.com) now to make it a better place.

Comment: Flagged as offensive. I am sick of this left wing "blame humans first" pro-robot propaganda.

Comment: @Jon: Is that your inferiority complex talking?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are a logged in user and have >= 200 reputation:

After successfully completing one captcha, we now suppress captcha for 5 minutes on your account.