# Human verification

Tags: discussion, support, captcha

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How many times is SO going to ask if I am human?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64644/how-many-times-is-so-going-to-ask-if-i-am-human)

I appreciate why we have human verification and think it is a good thing, but I am confused as to why I get it so often. 3 times today already, twice yesterday.

Annoyingly, it always seems to happen when I am answering a question from the train, have limited signal, and am fighting to be the first answer in. I don't even know if this could be the reason why somehow.

The question is - am I using Stack Overflow in such a way that it is specifically targeting me as a bot? If so, what behaviour do I need to avoid to stop being targeted so often? It is very annoying and often causes my answers to be delayed by 5-10 mins, until I get to another good signal patch.

Comment: Anecdotally I remember hitting the CAPTCHA more often than usual during the summer when I was somewhere in the middle of the Aegean (boat programming IRL) and network signal was shaky.

Comment: Also strangely it only happens on my iPad. Never iPhone or laptop. Also often soon after or just before "sorry something bad happened"

Comment: Nice try robot.

Comment: @YannisRizos What would you recommend for someone who wishes to start programming on a boat?

Comment: @mikeTheLiar Always use floats

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it's happening because instead of typing a character at a time like a human, your data is being sent in bursts as you pass into areas of reception. SO sees this as you typing faster than a human could. When I paste a lot of text in from my editor, I find it gives me a captcha unless I also do a little manual editing before submitting. Your poor reception (or buffering in the transmission to your network) is preventing single characters coming through at a time.

Comment: Switching IP addresses (quite common with mobile connections) also triggers the checks.