# Is it kosher to ask a canonical version of an oft-asked question whose answer we can then link to?

Tags: discussion

Several times a week on [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) a new user discovers a site that uses AJAX for the first time and asks a question along the lines of "what is this black magic!?". Said question is promptly downvoted to oblivion for having done no research.

I lieu of that, I would like to be able to suggest their questions be merged with some "basics of AJAX" question, but I haven't been able to find one whose answer entirely covers everything I'd like (except maybe [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536609/how-to-start-learning-ajax)).

My question is this, if I can't find a good question, is it the socially correct thing to do here to ask a question whose answer would point these people in the right direction and then merge all their questions with that? (or, suggestions for a question that has already been asked)

Comment: Only if you separate meat and dairy questions.

Comment: @Rosinante: I think nwellcome is talking about more of a meat and potatoes question.

Comment: @Popular: I got it. I was just trying to make a little joke of my own.

Comment: @Josh, don't worry, we got it, evidence suggests that Popular is a robot: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59910/i-am-not-an-electronic-gadget/59943#59943 and thus unable to parse our meat-brained humor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this is allowed and even explicitly encouraged:

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/

> Help us build a great library of canonical answers. If you keep seeing the same form of questions, whether it’s mod_rewrite rules on Server Fault, freezing computers on Super User, or how to use regular expressions to parse HTML, **write a great, canonical answer, once and for all.** Make it community wiki so that as many other people as possible can make it great. Work really hard on writing something that is clear, concise, and understandable by as wide an audience as possible.

Comment: Sort of. The OP is asking about asking a canonical question to which a canonical answer can be provided (and ideally linked to from a tag faq), a process that is still fraught with difficulties.

Comment: I would add that it should be made community wiki _only_ when there are at least 3 other contributors who have made significant additions to the answer. Otherwise, the "community" aspect is missing and the OP should not be denied his rep for the effort.

Answer (score 1):

If someone with experience in MySQL wants to do something similar, there are [88 non-closed questions about "`mysql server has gone away`"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22mysql%20server%20has%20gone%20away%22%20closed:0). Maybe there is already a canonical question/answer between these (or maybe most of these are really different), but I didn't find it quickly.