# Improved favorite system: creating personal FAQ pages

Tags: feature-request, bookmarks

I'm using Stack Overflow quite often as a resource to find answers to commonly occurring design problems. Especially when working in a team or on the same project the identical questions are occurring, or people want references to coding style decisions.

Thus I want to categorize questions for topic related frequently asked questions, that is,

- answers to design questions often occurring in our project.
- a personal FAQ on most common C++ design problems.
- a personal lookup list for patterns, that I prefer

Ideally, one would create a list of his favourite questions and could share a link or embed this on the project homepage.

Comment: What is the benefit of having a personal FAQ page hosted on Stack Overflow rather than using an existing service like delicious.com, a wiki, or a blog?

Comment: @Bill: The point is that the questions and answers are already here at stack overflow. Instead of managing a set of links to stack overflow at an external page keeping it on the page actually puts them where they belong in my opinion. As a clarification, it's  not about creating new questions here, but about managing questions that already exist to unite them to some bigger context. In the worst case it can be used to find duplicates on this site more quickly for certain topics.

Comment: If you're interested in helping to more easily find duplicates, the best way to go is to close *existing* duplicates and point them to a canonical question & answer: the system will recognize this and suggest the original in the future.

Comment: @Nine is that really worthwhile doing though? You cast one close vote out of five required. What are the odds of those four other votes ever materializing on a question that is no longer on the front page?

Comment: Not *great*, @TheP.G.RepMiningCo. - however, we now have [a public list of all questions with at least one duplicate vote](http://stackoverflow.com/review/close?s=1&pagesize=15&filter=all&customsort=lowestscore&no-random=1&close-reason=1), filterable by tag, so if, say, several PHP users wanted to collaborate on improving the [implicit PHP FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php?sort=faq), they could spend some time reviewing [possibly duplicate PHP questions](http://stackoverflow.com/review/close?s=1&filter=all&customsort=lowestscore&tag=php&no-random=1&close-reason=1)...

Comment: @Nine oh, cool! Didn't know that. Now add to that [a reward for finding dupe questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90620/reward-finding-duplicate-questions-10-2-5), and I'm sure those will get cleaned up in no time!

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a nice idea, but it's not something that needs to be in Stack Overflow's core  feature set IMO. The system is complex enough already with all the new network sites and such. As Bill suggests, using a Wiki or Blog should work well for this.

Maybe somebody wants to build an app for it using the V2 API - there's even the chance of winning some nice [gear](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/12/stack-exchange-api-v2-0-public-beta/)!

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can do this now...

- If you click the little "star" next to a voting buttons on a question, it'll be added to [your publicly-visible list of favorites](https://stackoverflow.com/users/887836/alex?tab=favorites).
- Once you have [sufficient reputation on the site](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/new-user) you can put links to whatever you want in your profile's "About me" section.

If these are lacking in some way, you'll have to be more specific about how you think they should be expanded, including your rationale for the changes.