# Tag synonyms and searching

Tags: bug, tags, search, tag-synonyms

In relation to an ongoing election, this post was mentioned: [Include information about elections in the newsletter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/121562). One of the tags on that question is [newsletter](/questions/tagged/newsletter), which is [a synonym](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/community-digests/synonyms) of [community-digests](/questions/tagged/community-digests).

I have noticed that:

- Searching for [[election] "cast your vote"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Belection%5D+%22cast+your+vote%22) shows this question among the results.
- But if I replace the [election](/questions/tagged/election) with [newsletter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bnewsletter%5D+%22cast+your+vote%22) or [community-digests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bcommunity-digests%5D+%22cast+your+vote%22), that question is no longer among the results.
- Trying [newsletter "cast your vote"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=newsletter+%22cast+your+vote%22) returns some results, including the question mentioned above - here I am searching for the word newsletter, not within the posts tagged [newsletter](/questions/tagged/newsletter).

Is this caused by the tag synonym?

Personally I would consider this a bug. (I'd expect that the two synonymized tags should behave more or less equivalently. At least, I would expect that one of the two searches should return this question.)

I am aware that I can find posts with the tag newsletter [using SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1190392/find-questions-containing-the-given-tag?tagName=newsletter) and in the same way I could search [for a specific string](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1237993/recent-questions-with-specific-word-in-the-body-in-the-given-tag?word=cast%20your%20vote&tagname=newsletter) in the given tag.
However, it would be more natural to have a possibility to find such post using the search function on the site.

Of course, if the cause is something different or if this is the expected behavior, I have no problem with retagging this question from [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) to [support](/questions/tagged/support).

---

After a [recent conversation in chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1632/conversation/searching-and-tag-synonyms) it seems that I should probably clarify the question a bit.
I might be wrong, but it seems to me, that problem like this happens in the following situations:

1. The post was tagged with a tag.
2. The synonym was created later (and the synonymized tag wasn't merged into the master tag).
3. And the post wasn't edited since then - so it still has the "old" tag.

Here are some other examples from this site I was able to find. (The links are always first to searches with the two synonymized tags and then for some other tag.)

- encyclopedia with [canonical-questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=encyclopedia+%5Bcanonical-questions%5D), [canonical](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=encyclopedia+%5Bcanonical%5D) and [self-answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=encyclopedia+%5Bself-answer%5D) (see [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/133538)).
- gamedev with [exploit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=gamedev+%5Bexploit%5D), [security](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=gamedev+%5Bexploit%5D) and [sock-puppets](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=gamedev+%5Bsock-puppets%5D) (see [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184850))
- timestamp missing with [date-format](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=timestamps+missing+%5Bdate-format%5D), [dates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=timestamps+missing+%5Bdates%5D) and [ios-app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=timestamps+missing+%5Bios-app%5D) (see [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/133538))