# Swag Request Delays for April/May

Tags: discussion, swag

I've been receiving a lot of requests for swag due to contests, conferences, elections, and many other reasons. This includes swag/prizes from the most recent Gaming event, as well. Many of you have noticed there have been significant delays in getting our users any swag at all.

I have to apologize; I should have made this announcement weeks ago, but I kept hoping things would work out before I had to write this post. Unfortunately, it seems that this strategy has backfired.

For some time, **we've been experiencing a major warehouse move** that coincided with our company's office move. The storage setup and taking inventory of our various and sundry swag has taken longer than expected, and **I have been waiting for the all-clear before I can put in swag orders**.

I have to thank all the users who have been patient with these delays so far, and I appreciate everyone who has been understanding and patient for the last several weeks. The most recent news I heard is: **everything should be sorted out by the end of next week** at the latest, after which point you will all begin receiving shipments in a more timely manner once more.

Please feel free to comment/answer here if you have specific questions about any requests you've made. Again, thank you all for your patience!

***Update***

As of July 2013 - we should be all caught up. Yay, us!!

If we were supposed to send you something and you didn't receive it, [contact us](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact/other) and let us know. Be sure to tell us:

- What you were supposed to get
- Why you were supposed to get it (e.g. won a contest, someone from the team offered you a shirt, etc)
- If it can be worn, we need your size.
- If you live on planet Earth, we need your complete address (as it should be printed on the package). Interplanetary delivery is still down, we're sorry for the inconvenience!

We'll get it sorted out quickly!

Comment: Thank You Very Much for the update! No problems about the Swag  Lag ;-)

Comment: You should write "everything should be sorted out within 6-8 weeks" this way even if it takes years, it's legitimate. ;)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd problem is, it's already been almost 4 weeks! :( If it takes 2 more, it stops being ironic and just starts becoming frustrating!

Comment: Conflicted: Happy about update, sad about delay, perplexed as to why robots were not involved in the move, after all SE is no place for humans. http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/59943/181695

Comment: @mattytommo We have a swag request process; orders have been backed up since late March because of vague Reasons -- this post is giving less-vague Reasons. :)

Comment: ....Seriously, three close votes?

Comment: @Aarthi guess people are getting frustrated... but you got diamond power no shame in using it! :-)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd pretty sure that's edging on mod abuse :P

Comment: @Aarthi suspending those who voted to close would be abuse of power... closing and reopening to clear the close votes won't. :-)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd meh those votes expire naturally.

Comment: Where do I vote for a shop or stackoverflow t-shirts? I found this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77556/dont-you-think-that-its-time-for-some-stack-exchange-shirts but it is OLD!

Comment: @mplungjan you can vote all you want, but [it sounds like the shop isn't coming back](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/137580/131713). (The author of the linked answer is Stack Exchange's CFO.)

Comment: @Aarthi I really hope the cause for your leaving Stack Exchange is not this delay?? :(

Answer (score 6):

I was supposed to receive an unspecified piece of swag back in March that never arrived. This isn't a complaint about the physical item — it's the thought that counts, really! — but I thought you might want the follow-up, since nobody else has posted. I don't know whether everyone else also forgot about pending swag requests, or if I'm the only one who had a problem; hopefully, this bump will lead to us finding out.

Comment: Can you e-mail me (tpost@stackexchange.com) and let me know what you were supposed to get and your shipping details?

Comment: Don't advertise that it's _that_ easy to get stuff out of you @Tim :-).

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards We have a special selection of garments that have been worn for WEEKS by our system administrators and not yet washed for those that attempt to acquire swag by such means. If you want the equivalent of a wearable, warm and _slightly_ damp embrace from [Peter Grace](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/170555/peter-grace) to go with your ill gotten swag - go for it.